# Create a matrix from a dict of dicts for calculating similarities between docs

Tags: matrix, nlp, similarity, tf-idf, word-embedding

Here is my problem:

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id   tfidf_weights   
1    {word1: 0.01, word2: 0.01, word3: 0.01, ...}
2    {word4: 0.01, word5: 0.01, word6: 0.01, ...}
3    {word7: 0.01, word8: 0.01, word9: 0.01, ...}
4    {word10: 0.01, word11: 0.01, word12: 0.01, ...}
5    {word13: 0.01, word14: 0.01, word15: 0.01, ...}    
.
.
.
```

column 'id' represent the ids of the docs and 'tfidf_weights' the tfidf weight for each word of each docs.

from this dataframe, i can obtain a dict with the following structure:

```
mydict = {1:{word1: 0.01, word2: 0.01, word3: 0.01, ...}, 2:{word4: 0.01, word5: 0.01, word6: 0.01, ...}, 3:{word7: 0.01, word8: 0.01, word9: 0.01, ...}, 4:{word10: 0.01, word11: 0.01, word12: 0.01, ...}, 5:{word13: 0.01, word14: 0.01, word15: 0.01, ...}, ...}
```

what i want to do is, from this dictionary, obtain a matrix like this:

```
      word1     word2     word3     word4   ...
1     0.01      0.01      0.01      0.01     
2     0.01      0.01      0.01      0.01
3     0.01      0.01      0.01      0.01
4     0.01      0.01      0.01      0.01
5     0.01      0.01      0.01      0.01
.
.
.
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a list of dictionaries into a dataframe by using the pandas DataFrame class directly.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [{"0": 0}, {"1": 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

To apply this to your problem, all you have to do is turn `mydict` into a list of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Yes but i need to convert it into a matrix not into a dataframe because i want to calculate similarities between docs and i believe you need a matrix of tfidf weights for each doc

Comment: You have multiple options: you could first convert it to a dataframe, and then call `df.as_matrix`. Alternatively,  you could use the `DictVectorizer` from `sklearn`, that will also take care of the problem for you.

Comment: Yes i have heard of DictVectorizer i will try that, thank you !